# Xcode ViewDidLoad animation Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, animation

I'm having some trouble with the animations in a tabbed app in Xcode.
I have the `viewDidLoad` and the `viewDidAppear` parts, the problem is that I have two labels `label1` and `label2`. I would like `label1` appearing only once when the application loads, and `label2` appearing every time I go back to the FirstView.

So the logical thing to do would be:

```
override func viewDidLoad(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.label1.alpha = 0
    self.label2.alpha = 0

    //this is the animation
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.label1.alpha = 1.0
        //this is what happens after a delay
        [DELAY CODE]
                self.label1.alpha = 0.0

    })
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.label2.alpha = 1.0

}
```

Essentially what this should do is make `label1` appear and disappear only once, and make `label2` appear every time `firstView` shows up on the screen. The problem is that I have an error in the first line telling me *"Method does not override any method from its superclass"*. So how can I do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the `animated:Bool` from your [`viewDidLoad`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad)-method. there is no such parameter in this method.

So it should look like that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
```

Comment: i'm pretty sure it didn't, but now it gives me a breakpoint on the next line

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0,
                        animations: { () -> Void in

                       // Your animation method
         self.label1.alpha = 1.0

                    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
                        // Call your delay method here.
                        // Delay - 3 seconds

               NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(NSTimeInterval(3),
                                        target: self, 
                                      selector: "hideLabel", 
                                      userInfo: nil, 
                                       repeats: false)
                    }
```

//

```
func hideLabel {

           UIView.animateWithDuration(2,
                  animations: { () -> Void in

                self.label1.alpha = 0.0
           })
}
```